# How to create an alias for print variables in Linux

Tags: sh

I'm learning a bit about Linux and I was wondering if someone could show me how to create an alias view that prints the value of the $PATH and $HOME variables. The answer to this I would say is something like this:

```sh
function path() {
  old=$IFS
  IFS=:
  printf "%s\n" $PATH
  IFS=$old
}
```

It is a type of training task in the book Linux Command Line and Shell Scripting Bible.

Comment: Could you add what do you expect? Your code do 95% of the task (and the difficult part)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that `$PATH` is still subject to pathname expansion, and (though unlikely) a directory on the path could *still* look like a glob that matches multiple files.

The correct way to write this in POSIX shell would be via repeated trimming of the value via parameter expansion.

```
path () {
    p=$PATH
    while :; do
        d=${p%%:*}
        printf '%s\n' "$d"
        [ "$d" = "$p" ] && break
        p=${p#*:}
    done
}
```

The fact that you are using the `function` keyword implies you are using `bash`, in which case it would be simpler to use an array.

```
path() {
    IFS=: read -a d <<< "$PATH"
    printf '%s\n' "${d[@]}"
}
```